# How to install Jenkins using cPanel?

Tags: java, jenkins, cpanel

1. How can I install Jenkins using only cPanel on non root account ie in  my `~/public_html`? Server provider forbid using shell so the cPanell is the only way?
2. Is it possible to install Jenkins as a root but the Jenkins proces would be used as a non-root user? In other words is it possible for root to grant only me access to using Jenkins in my `~`?

Answer (score 3):

1. It can't be installed due to incompatible server, I'm assuming your cpanel uses apache httpd server while jenkins need a servlet container like tomcat server.
2. Please see my answer on 1.

Comment: Ok so is the best bet to install Jenkins? Do i have to be root with Tomcat running to use Jenkins? And the only way to give privileges to non-root users is with Jenkins web interface? ie treat jenkins as CMS service?

Comment: Yes and no need for root access as long as you can put jenkins war file on tomcat's web directory, it will autodeploy the war and will be accessible via http://hostname:8080/jenkins. Yes that is right using the Jenkings web interface.

Comment: I have installed Jenkins from repo Jenkins provide for Centos. That is I gues the most convinient. But it is not using tomcat but its embedded server. Is there no problem with its performance?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be happen using shared hosting with no root access
You should have vps to do that

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Hosting provider that sell cpanel shared accounts give limited access to users on the shared hosting, And because you can't install jenkins withoout root access, then you can't install jenkins on shared hosting .. The only way is to buy VPS or dedicated account to have that root access.

Comment: You can't install jenkins without root access, and while shared hosting root account is used to manage multiple users with multiple cpanel accounts including you, you can't use jenkins on cpanel without root access, also with jenkins you need control over host ports which not provided with shared hosting providers.